# How to prevent Meteor from installing own .android

Tags: android, meteor, android-bundle

Meteor installs its own bundle of Android devices in ~/.meteor/android_bundle/.android. But actually there is already a copy of that in ~/.android.

Since it takes more than 1GB of space, does it make sense to have two different copies and if not, can you somehow tell Meteor to take the ~/.android folder files instead?

Comment: I guess you could remove the actual android folder in there and replace it with a symlink to ~/.android

Comment: You're hired :)
Haven't thought about this simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Also from Meteor Cordova Phonegap integration:

`env USE_GLOBAL_ADK=t meteor run android`